# How can I use output of sub-query in SELECT clause in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, subquery

This is about SQL Server 2005 onward.
How can I use output of sub-query in `SELECT` clause in `WHERE` clause?

Student_Master

```
Student_Id  Student_Name    
1           A
2           B
3           C
```

Student_Details

```
Student_Id  Student_Info
1           1_Info1
2           2_Info1
2           2_Info2
2           2_Info3
```

I want to fetch all columns from table Student_Master and COUNT(Student_Details.Student_Info) where student info count > 0.

Expected output: -

```
Student_Id  Student_Name    InfoCount
1           A               1
2           B               3
```

Following is INCORRECT syntax but to explain what I am trying to do: -

```
SELECT Student_Id, Student_Name, 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student_Details
  WHERE Student_Master.Student_Id = Student_Details.Student_Id
) AS InfoCount
FROM Student_Master
WHERE InfoCount > 0
```

I know that following CORRECT syntax works: -

```
SELECT Student_Id, Student_Name, 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student_Details
  WHERE Student_Master.Student_Id = Student_Details.Student_Id
) AS InfoCount
FROM Student_Master
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student_Details
  WHERE Student_Master.Student_Id = Student_Details.Student_Id
)> 0
```

But here, I have to write same sub query twice. This sub-query will execute twice and will it hit performance. Master table has 25 million records and details table has 100 million records.

Indexes and other optimizations are ok, but I want to write most optimized query in first place.

Comment: This should work for you http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: @JamieD77 - Thanks for quick reply but HAVING clause does not work. It says "Invalid column name InfoCount".   Same is the problem with my "INCORRECT syntax" in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way and easier to write using the APPLY as follows:

```
SELECT Student_Master.*, InfoCount
FROM Student_Master
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) InfoCount FROM Student_Details
WHERE Student_Details.Student_Id=Student_Master.Student_Id ) InfoCounts
WHERE InfoCount>0
```

This is also optimized as the query plan as follows: 
[image]

Comment: why would you `OUTER APPLY` if you're using the value in your `WHERE` clause?  `CROSS APPLY` would work better and give the same result as `OUTER APPLY`

Comment: @Atheer Mostafa - What will be the performance impact if I filter outer query based on some criteria (say Student_Id < 10000000) which qualifies only half records from master table? **Will sub query still execute for all the (2.5 crore) records in master table?** or only for filtered records?

Comment: @JamieD77 the OUTER APPLY will do a clustered index seek, which is much better performance.

Comment: @AJ as the I show in the Query Execution Plan, this query using OUTER APPLY will perform using CLUSTERED INDEX SEEK which is fastest. It will do minimum IO overhead.

Answer (score 3):

If you just **Inner Join** `Student_Master` to `Student_Details` you will only get records that have a `count > 0`

```
SELECT  Student_Id,
        Student_Name,
        COUNT(*) InfoCount
FROM    Student_Master sm
        JOIN Student_Details sd ON sm.Student_Id = sd.Student_Id
GROUP BY Student_Id,
        Student_Name
```

If for some reason you need to find records with a count greater than one, then you would use **Group By Having**

```
SELECT  Student_Id,
        Student_Name,
        COUNT(*) InfoCount
FROM    Student_Master sm
        JOIN Student_Details sd ON sm.Student_Id = sd.Student_Id
GROUP BY Student_Id,
        Student_Name
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you want to avoid large Group by statements you can just inner join to a sub query here.

```
SELECT  sm.Student_Id,
        sm.Student_Name,
        ic.InfoCount
FROM    Student_Master sm
        INNER JOIN (
                SELECT  Student_Id, COUNT(*) InfoCount
                FROM    Student_Details 
                GROUP BY Student_Id 
            ) ic ON sm.Student_Id = ic.Student_Id
```

Comment: This solution works perfect with only one drawback. I have to add each column from select clause in group by clause except aggregate function. There are 34 columns in select clause. Will this hit performance or mal-affect in any other way?

Comment: Well you can inner join to a subquery here also to avoid having to use that many group bys.  See update